# Why does the dygraph generate multiple lines when I just want two lines?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, visualization, data-visualization, dygraphs

I just want to draw two lines but it generate multiple lines that can overlap together. And the x-axe time sometimes disappears.
[Here is the graph generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqDfS.jpg)

[After zoom in you can see the points are actually the top sharpes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7teie.png)

**Here is my code :**

```
g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("chartConatiner-"+$scope.graphIndex[j]),$scope.LcDataList[j]['data'].sort(Comparator2),{labels: $scope.LcDataList[j]['opts']['labels'], title: $scope.LcDataList[j]['opts']['title'], axes: {
                                x: {

                                valueFormatter: Dygraph.dateString_,
                                axisLabelFormatter: Dygraph.dateAxisFormatter,
                                ticker: Dygraph.dateTicker

                                }
                                }})
```

Comment: Can you post the Data you initialize the dygraph with? My guess is the second line is from a data point drawing from [0,0] to something like [0.5,500] or reverse.

Comment: Thank you. this problem has already been solved when I transfer data type to csv. Do you mind to answer my another question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535171/can-dygraph-show-the-annotation-dynamically-from-the-data)  ?